# Try block throws exception, but catch block does not catch it

Tags: android, kotlin, google-signin

I am using google login and I'm getting an exception. However, it looks like I'm unable to catch it.

I have the following code:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        when (requestCode) {
            RC_SIGN_IN -> {
                val task = try{
                    GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                } catch (e: ApiException) {
                    Log.d("EXCEPTION", e.message)
                    when(e.statusCode) {
                        12501 -> return
                        else -> {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            return
                        }
                    }
                }
...
```

From Logcat I can see, that `ApiException` is the right Exception to catch:

[image]

And its definetly the one I am catching:

[image]

At first I thought the direct assignment with `val task = try...` might be responsible for this for some reason, so I changed my code accordingly and tried this:

```
var task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>?
try{
    task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
} catch (e: ApiException) {
    Log.d("EXCEPTION", e.message)
    when(e.statusCode) {
       12501 -> task = null
       else -> {
           e.printStackTrace()
           task = null
       }
    }
}
```

Still, same behavior. So I thought maybe there *is* another exception being thrown, so I added another catch block:

```
var task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>?
try{
    task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
} catch (e: ApiException) {
    Log.d("EXCEPTION", e.message)
    when(e.statusCode) {
       12501 -> task = null
       else -> {
           e.printStackTrace()
           task = null
       }
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Log.d("EXCEPTION", e.message)
    task = null
}
```

Still the same behavior. I have spotted this code with breakpoints on every step but it just ignores the catch block completely. I stop at the try block:

[image]

But if I resume, the next step is outside of my try-catch block.

[image]

Can someone explain that behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as I asked this question, I realized something:

The catch block is ignored because the try block doesn't really throw an exception.

The `task` object is set and its the one that holds the exception. When the `task` object is used later like this: `val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)` then that's where the exception is actually thrown. At least that's what I expect here. The exception itself is basically caught, kept and thrown at a later point in time, but with the old stacktrace...

Not 100% sure about the inner workings of this, but that's what I could tell from logcat and my code.

So, instead of a try-catch, I simply went and handled the exception manually:

```
val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
if(task.exception != null) {
    val e = task.exception as? ApiException
    if(e != null) {
        when(e.statusCode) {
            12501 -> return
            else -> {
                e.printStackTrace()
                return
            }
        }
    } else {
        task.exception?.printStackTrace()
    }
    return
}
```